# the meaning of "peeling paint" in the mentioned sentence.

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> they tend not to include black activists' campaigns against lead
>   poisoning caused by **peeling paint** in city slum apartments.
>   ([Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=h1ZDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22campaigns%20against%20lead%20poisoning%20caused%20by%20peeling%20paint%22&source=bl&ots=dLgnPN1xJK&sig=DNhqoN1TYJAIya8mpQQHw8fdfPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw0IDQ5JTaAhVBLVAKHSlgBIsQ6AEILDAA))

Comment: This is the ordinary meaning of *peeling* and of *paint*, which you should be able to find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When paint gets old, it begins to crack and eventually come apart in flakes. We call this "peeling off". So then *peeling paint* refers to paint that is peeling off.

Your example sentence is talking about lead paint. When lead paint peels off, it releases lead into the air, which is toxic to people.